# Network Service Discovery (mDNS) on react-native/Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, zeroconf, mdns

I have an IOT device ruining a mDNS responder, is there a way to find the device through a react-native/Expo app?

- I have found a react-native library ([react-native-zeroconf](https://github.com/balthazar/react-native-zeroconf)). However, it requires react-native-link which expo does not support.
- I have also found a pure Java Script library ([multicast-dns](https://github.com/mafintosh/multicast-dns)). However, I'm not sure whether it is possible to port that to react-native/Expo.

Should I detach and use native modules? I'm keeping that as a last resort for now.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? It's so frustrating that android is not supporting mDNS out of the box :(

Comment: i gave up on this feature :/

Comment: @JoséRobertoCanutoVasconcelo - did `react-native-zeroconf` worked for you?

Comment: @Varun unfortunately no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one you can do with expo but you will need to detach.

The second will not work at all because it assumes the node API which does not exist in ReactNative.

Comment: i am trying zeroconf with RN Metro, but have no luck any guidance please